# Loop through files which do not contain certain texts in makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, find

I want to go through a set of files in `makefile`:

```
alltest:    all
            for f in $(FILES); do \
                echo $$f; \
            done
```

I want to write `$(FILES)` such that it regards the files of `/abc/*.txt` which do not contain `ERROR1` or `ERROR2` in their body.

Too look for a set of files which contain `ERROR1` or `ERROR2` in their body, I use `find -iname '/abc/*.txt' | xargs grep -e "ERROR1" -e "ERROR2"`

Could anyone tell me how to do the complement of the set, also how to integrate the shell command into the makefile?

Comment: Before you do it in `make`, how would you do it in shell?  What have you tried?

Comment: I just edited a little bit the code... in shell, I only use `grep` from time to time... the commands to find files look too complicated to me...

Comment: The shell is a programming language — reasonably well suited to the manipulation of files by programs.  Which language do you program in?  Think about what you'd do in that language.  Assume you can generate a list of file names.  How do you find the files that contain ERROR4 in their body (hint: `grep` with options can tell you)?  How would you remove the names from the list (hint: `comm` can compare sorted lists of values)?  How would you find files that contain `ERROR1` or `ERROR2` or `ERROR3` in line 1?  This is probably the hardest task.  How do you remove those files from the list.

Comment: Do you have GNU `grep`?  Have you looked at its option list (which is rather extensive: `grep --help`)?  Negatives (doesn't contain ERROR, especially on a particular line) are relatively hard to deal with.  But you can at least think about how you'd write a shell script that, given a list of names, returns a list of names that meet your criteria.  And then you can put that in a `bin` directory on your `$PATH` and use it in your `makefile`, can't you?

Comment: I just amended a little bit OP...

Comment: `grep` has a `-l` option to just print the filenames that contain a match. However, I'm not aware of an option to do the opposite, print the filenames that don't contain a match. You can use `-q` to make `grep` silent, just setting its return value, and then use `if ! grep -q ...`

Comment: @Barmar: that's why I suggested `grep --help`.  For version 2.14 (determined from `grep --version`), the output contains: `-L, --files-without-match  print only names of FILEs containing no match` and on the next line `-l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs containing matches`.  I don't know them all either; I came across this one on SO this morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first…does this do what you think and want?

```
find -iname '/abc/*.txt'
```

It doesn't find files in a subdirectory for me (on Mac OS X 10.8.5).  Where `find . -iname '*.txt'` finds some files, `find . -iname '/path/*.txt` produces no output, and neither does `-ipath`.  However, `find . -ipath '*/path/*.txt'` does produce a list of files.  So, for the time being, we'll correct your `find` command to:

```
find . -ipath '*/abc/*.txt'
```

Next, you run:

```
xargs grep -e "ERROR1" -e "ERROR2"
```

This will produce lines with both the names of the files and the message.  If you wanted the names of the files which include a match, you need to add `-l` to the command:

```
find . -ipath '*/abc/*.txt' |
xargs grep -l -e "ERROR1" -e "ERROR2"
```

However, you want to list only the files that do not match.  For that, if you have GNU `grep`, you can use the `-L` option:

```
find . -ipath '*/abc/*.txt' |
xargs grep -L -e "ERROR1" -e "ERROR2"
```

If you don't have GNU `grep`, then you have to work a lot harder:

```
find . -ipath '*/abc/*.txt' |
tee file.names |
xargs grep -l -e "ERROR1" -e "ERROR2" > matching.file.names
comm -23 file.names matching.file.names
```

The `tee` command captures a copy of the list of file names in the file `file.names` (such originality).  The `grep` command captures the list of matching file names in `matching.file.names`.  The names will be in the same order in both files.  The ones that appear in `file.names` but not in `matching.file.names` are the ones you want.  By default, the `comm file.names matching.file.names` command would print 3 columns: those lines found only in the first file, those found only in the second file, and those found in both files.  By suppressing the output of columns 2 and 3 with the `-23` option, we get only the names in the first file that are not found in the other — which is the list you want.

Where you take the list from there is up to you…

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At the moment I write for **f in `find . -ipath ...`**, do you know how to make a variable for **`find . -ipath ...`** so that the structure looks better?

Comment: I just realize that it doesn't work perfectly, do you have any idea about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948227/an-odd-behavior-of-find ?

Comment: Funnily enough, I was looking at that question when the notice about this comment arrived...I'll go back to looking at it.  There are all sorts of things that might need to be resolved with this.  It was 'notes towards' a solution rather than a production-ready solution.